# Есть картинка и есть рамка которая должна быть на картинке по центру вертикально и горизонтально?

Tags: bootstrap

Есть картинка и есть рамка которая должна быть на картинке по центру вертикально и горизонтально. Сделать на bootstrap
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container_form_main {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding-bottom: 135px;
}

.container_border {
 display: flex;
 vertical-align: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90%;

 border: 5px solid #ffcb2f;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container_form_main container-fluid">
        <img src="images/form.jpg" class="img-fluid container_form_main container-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="container container_border"></div>
```

Comment: ещё нужно это всё написать на всю ширину

Comment: чего чего? картинку хоть приложите желаемого результата

Comment: https://img4.goodfon.com/original/1366x768/6/e3/kapli-voda-listia-zelen.jpg

Comment: и где тут рамка горизонтально и вертикально по центру?

Comment: Я это и прошу сделать!

Comment: а я вас прошу объяснить, что означает "рамка горизонтально и вертикально по центру" как вы себе это представляете. нарисуйте в паинте как это выглядит вообще.